# Why does sparklyr function spark_read_csv take so long and eventually brakes?

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

I need to upload a large dataset from a CSV file to a Spark Cluster that I built following the guide provided by RStudio (https://spark.rstudio.com/examples/stand-alone-aws/), and run some data manipulation in R. I am using the sparklyr package, and I have an issue with the function spark_read_csv. It works nicely for tiny datasets (the CSV in the example has 10 rows). As soon as the size increases (1000 rows), the function submits a spark job that arrives at 90% in about 30 minutes, and then it never completes until I abort the process. Ideally, I need to upload a dataset that has ~2 M rows and it's 800 MB large.

I tried uploading the data with PySpark, which seems to work nicely and fast, but then I fail to fetch the data in R for the next steps I need to run in R. I tried in different servers (IBM Cloud, Amazon EC2 Instances, local laptop) but all give the same problem.

```r
sc <- spark_connect(master="spark://ip-xxxxx.eu-central-1.compute.internal:7077", 
                    version = "2.1.0",
                    spark_home = "/home/ubuntu/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/")

train <- spark_read_csv(sc, "train", "/home/ubuntu/train.csv")
```

I expect this to be fast for large files, but it takes way too long and eventually gets stuck. So what's the point of Spark? Shouldn't be one of the fasted solutions to deal with a large dataset that R cannot handle in memory?!?

Comment: Try  `memory = FALSE` - `sparklyr` defaults, with eager in-memory caching, are completely useless.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that. What I did was to switch to Databricks and could upload large files easily. I will try again configuring my own cluster and use your suggestion next time I have to do this job.